# REST endpoint by Spring @Component, validation

Tags: spring, rest, validation, components

REST endpoint implemented by Spring @Component. 
Is it possible to validate @RequestBody from POST method Using Hibernate Validator(@DecimalMax, @NotEmpty, etc, annotations in DTO) and @Valid annotation for @RequestBody or only by Spring Bean Validation implementing Validator interface?
Thanks in advance.